# Creating a PHP socket server for game

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, sockets

I am developing a game, well have an idea for a game and have been learning the languages I thought I needed for the project. It's a simple web based 2 player text based clone of Global Thermonuclear War.

Players login via A PHP form and are automatically matched. The game logic is fairly simple. Player A picks one of Player B's territories to attack, the move goes to the server which then sends it to Player B. Player B then makes a move and on it goes until there are no territories left. I've been learning Javascript and AJAX and can get around in PHP.

The problem I'm having is I can't seem to find anything relevant to creating game servers in php.

Can someone suggest some material I could read up on, or where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some project links -

http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/

http://code.google.com/p/php-websocket-server/

With APE (based on C), you could real time communication between server and client.

http://www.ape-project.org/

Comment: Many thanks! Only looked at the first link so far but this seems to be exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Read about Node.js, it's a Javascript framework. Combined to websockets on your browser, it can do some pretty amazing things. For example, Facebook is basically using a node.js-like server to keep the user up to date about notifications, Facebook chat or messages.

You could use this to keep a connection between a client and the server who'll have to handle the actions (Interacting with database, the user and the client's browser).

It's easy to use and very quick to build a server using node.js, associated to websockets, it should do what you're asking for.

Comment: the title is "Creating a PHP socket server for game", websockets were a good hint, but node.js advertising was unnecessary

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I have lots to read up on now. Just needed to know where to go next and once again the stack community have helped.